Rolling KPI calculations in polars, index not visible
How to add rolling KPI's to original dataframe in polars? when I do group by, I am not seeing an index and so cant join? I want to keep all original columns in dataframe intact but add rolling kpi to the dataframe?
Pandas code:
groups_df = df[mask_for_filter].groupby(['group_identifier'])
rolling_kpi = groups_df[['col_1', 'col_2']].rolling(15, min_periods=1, center=True).median().reset_index(level='group_identifier').sort_index()

df.loc[mask_for_filter, 'col_1_median'] = rolling_kpi['col_1']
df.loc[mask_for_filter, 'col_2_median'] = rolling_kpi['col_2']

Polars:
df = df.filter(mask_for_filter).group_by('group_identifier').agg(
    col_1_median=pl.col('col_1').rolling_median(15, min_periods=1, center=True),
    col_2_median=pl.col('col_2').rolling_median(15, min_periods=1, center=True))

Code: result_df should be same as df, except that with extra rolling median columns which is not happening in above....plus there is no index so can't merge/join
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
data = {
    'group_identifier': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], 100),
    'col_1': np.random.randn(100).round(2),
    'col_2': np.random.randn(100).round(2),
    'other_col': np.random.randn(100).round(2)
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

mask_for_filter = df['col_1'] > 0

result_df = df.filter(mask_for_filter).group_by('group_identifier').agg(
    col_1_median=pl.col('col_1').rolling_median(15, min_periods=1, center=True),
    col_2_median=pl.col('col_2').rolling_median(15, min_periods=1, center=True)
)


Please add sample data and expected output to the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

mask_for_avg is not defined anywhere.

Do you want the result to have the same rows as df or as result_df. If the former: What rolling median should be assigned to rows in df with pl.col(col_1) <= 0.

It looks like you don't need to group by, but to run rolling_median() over window instead.

over() to limit calculation to be within group_identifier.
name.suffix() to assign names to the new columns.

If you only need filtered rows:
(
    df
    .filter(mask_for_filter)
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("col_1", "col_2")
        .rolling_median(15, min_periods=1, center=True)
        .over("group_identifier")
        .name.suffix("_median")
    )
)

┌──────────────────┬───────┬───────┬───────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ group_identifier ┆ col_1 ┆ col_2 ┆ other_col ┆ col_1_median ┆ col_2_median │
│ ---              ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---          ┆ ---          │
│ str              ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64       ┆ f64          ┆ f64          │
╞══════════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ B                ┆ 0.01  ┆ 1.68  ┆ 1.12      ┆ 0.83         ┆ -0.46        │
│ B                ┆ 0.37  ┆ -0.26 ┆ 0.04      ┆ 0.85         ┆ -0.66        │
│ A                ┆ 0.72  ┆ -0.38 ┆ 0.47      ┆ 0.93         ┆ -0.44        │
│ A                ┆ 0.36  ┆ -0.51 ┆ -0.4      ┆ 0.86         ┆ -0.5         │
...
└──────────────────┴───────┴───────┴───────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘

Or, if you need this in your original DataFrame

when/then() twice - top one to only assign rolling median to rows which has col_1 > 0 and second one to not include rows to be filtered into the calculation of rolling median.

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("col_1") > 0).then(
            pl.when(pl.col("col_1") > 0).then(pl.col("col_1", "col_2"))
            .rolling_median(15, min_periods=1, center=True)
            .over("group_identifier")
        )
        .name.suffix("_median")
    )
)

If you want to add more aggregates you could generalize it (although I'm not sure if it's readable enough to go to production):
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("col_1") > 0).then(
            transform(
                pl.when(pl.col("col_1") > 0).then(pl.col("col_1", "col_2")),
                15, min_periods=1, center=True
            )
            .over("group_identifier")
        )
        .name.suffix(suffix)
        for transform, suffix in [
            (pl.Expr.rolling_median, "_median"),
            (pl.Expr.rolling_mean, "_mean"),
        ]
    )
)


Very cool, I think followup are not appropriate but will ask, if I want to do rolling mean as well as rolling median, does it make sense to repeat the above block with mean or is there cleaner way to do in above itself?

I've added some possibility to the answer
